# How to make value attribute in the select option tag to have url's in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I want value attribute in the select option menu to contain url's and on click should take to the particular path.I am using helper method to build the path

Code:

```
<%= select_tag :account, options_from_collection_for_select(Account.all,build_path_for_airline(id),"name") %>
```

helper:

```
def build_path_for_airline(id)
      new_path = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.path)
      new_path[:airline_id] = id
      new_path
    end
```

Unfortunately its not working as expected, Can anyone let me know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select), the `value_method` parameter is exactly that, a method. You can't use an arbitrary block of code and expect it to work.

You should implement your `build_path_for_airline` as an helper method in your model class, and use that method in the `options_from_collection_for_select` call.

```rb
# app/models/account.rb

class Account
  # ...
  def airline_path
    # Build the airline path for the current account
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/views/...

<%= select_tag :account, options_from_collection_for_select(Account.all, :airline_path, :name) %>
```

Comment: I am getting "undefined local variable or method `request' for #<Class:0x000000001216fac8>" error if I define the helper method in account.rb

Answer (score 2):

Richard-Degenne's answer is correct, but there's an alternative to putting the method in your model. `options_from_collection_for_select` can also take a lambda for its `value_method` argument:

```
<%= select_tag :account, options_from_collection_for_select(
      Account.all,
      ->(account){ build_path_for_airline(account.id) },
      "name")
%>
```

Comment: Interesting. I couldn't find it in the docs, though. Did you find that somewhere else?

Comment: @Richard-Degenne It's not documented, of course. Yay Rails. For what it's worth, though, several other methods in the FormOptionsHelper module also take a `value_method` option and it *is* documented for them, e.g. [`collection_select`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select): "The `:value_method` and `:text_method` parameters … can also be any object that responds to `call`, such as a `proc`, that will be called for each member of the `collection` to retrieve the value/text."